# Denying all IPs in App Engines's firewall, except communication between internal services in a project

Tags: google-app-engine

Let's say we have four services within an App Engine project. We want to block all incoming traffic, but we want these four services to communicate. To block for traffic, we simply set the default firewall rule to deny all IPs. However, this rule also blocks traffic *internally* between our services, so the services are blocked. How can we *easily* whitelist our internal services (using the standard environment) ?

Comment: In this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/understanding-firewalls#allowing_incoming_requests_from_your_services) it is mentioned that allowing `0.1.0.40/32` but when using URL Fetch. I'm not sure if this works with newer runtimes, can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios :

1. If the four services in App Engine Project are in the same VPC
   network (default/auto mode network)

   You have by default the following [implied rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) :

- `Default-allow-internal` - which helps communication among the services
  in the same VPC in same project. Allows ingress connections for all
  protocols and ports among instances in the network. This rule has the
  second-to-lowest priority of 65534, and it effectively permits
  incoming connections to VM instances from others in the same network.
  This rule allows traffic in 10.128.0.0/9 (from 10.128.0.1 to
  10.255.255.254), a range that covers all subnets in the network.
- `Implied ipv4/ipv6 deny ingress` - An ingress rule whose default action
  is deny, source is ::/0, and priority is the lowest possible (65535)
  protects all instances by blocking incoming connections to them.
- `Implied ipv4/ipv6 allow egress` - An egress rule whose action is
  allow, destination is ::/0, and priority is the lowest possible
  (65535) lets any instance send traffic to any destination, except for
  traffic blocked by Google Cloud.

  So if you are using the default VPC network and all your services are
  in the same network, you already have default internal communication
  between services and denied ingress traffic.

2. If the four services in App Engine Project are in the different VPC
   networks, then you can use [Ingress Controls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/application-security#ingress_controls).

   By default, your App Engine app receives all HTTP requests that are
   sent to its [appspot URL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-routed) or to a [custom domain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/mapping-custom-domains) that you have
   configured for your app. You can use network ingress controls to restrict
   traffic so that your app only receives HTTP requests from specific
   sources :

- `All`: Default. Your app will receive all traffic, including direct
  requests sent from the internet.
- `Internal and Cloud Load Balancing`: Your app will only receive
  requests that are routed through [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-routed#load_balancer), or that are
  sent from VPC networks in the same project. All other requests are
  denied with a 403 error.
- `Internal-only`: Your app will only receive requests that are sent from
  VPC networks in the same project. All other requests are denied with
  a 403 error

You can change your default ingress control for your App Engine Project and set it to `internal-only` to allow your app to receive requests from services in different VPC networks but inside the same App Engine Project. This is how you can edit the [ingress settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/application-security#edit_ingress_settings) for your App Engine Project.